# How to make categorical limits unique?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category where all small limits exist, i.e., for every functor $F:I\to C$ from a small category there is a *cone* $(L,\ell_X)_{X\in I}$ over $F$, i.e., $\ell_X:L\to F(X)$ are $C$-morphisms such that, for all $I$-morphisms $f:X\to Y$, we have $F(f)\circ \ell_X=\ell_Y$, which is *universal*, i.e., for every other cone $(M,m_X)_{X\in I}$, there is a unique $\bar m:M\to L$ with
$m_X=\ell_X\circ\bar m$ for all $X\in I$.

Limits are *unique up to unique isomorphism* and this is usually taken as an argument to talk about **the** limit of the functor. This has obvious advantages, e.g., if one wants to talk about properties of limits or things like *commutativity*.

Anyway, limits are not unique literally so that the definit article can be in fact dangerous (for instance, if categorical notions are mixed with non-categorical arguments in a particular category). It would thus be good if one could, at least in principle, make limits unique.

In his Tohoku article, Grothendieck proposes to choose (once and for all using Hilbert's $\tau$-symbol) a limit for every functor (maybe he writes this only for products) but it seems to me that then a statement like *the product of the limits of two functors $F$ and $G$ is the limit of the product $F\times G$* (which sends $X\in I$ to $F(X)\times G(X)$ and similarly for morphisms) need not be literally true because the choice of the limits might not have taken care of this.

Another way would be to replace the category $C$ by a skeleton so that isomorphic objects are equal. But this solves the problem only for limit objects which are only a small part of the limit cone! There are still many automorphisms on $L$ which can be used to produce many different limits.

I could imagine hat the Yoneda embedding of $C$ into the the category of presheaves on $C$ might be helpful (perhaps only for small categories) if one is willing to choose a fixed meaning of limits in the category of sets (e,g,, **the** cartesian product as **a** categorical product, although one has still the problem that, e.g., with Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs, $(X\times Y)\times Z$ and $X\times (Y\times Z)$ are not equal literally).

**Questions**.

- Is there a standard way in category theory to deal with this problem?
- Is there a very strong axiom of choice which allows to choose unique limits such that statements like for the product of functors become literally true?
- Is there a way to reduce the skeleton futher in a way that the identity of an object is the only automorphism?

Comment: This is not considered a serious problem in category theory. It is known to be impossible to make the cartesian product strictly associative in all cases. The number of automorphisms of an object is invariant under equivalences of categories so you cannot eliminate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem. Category theorists just never use arguments that would require limits to be literally unique, and it turns out this is good enough.

Speaking more philosophically, uniqueness up to unique isomorphism just is the correct generalization of literal uniqueness to category theory; it says that the space of possibilities for the limit is a category equivalent to the terminal category $1$, also known as a contractible category. If we [always insist](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) on working up to equivalence there's no way to do better than this as far as uniqueness goes. Similarly in $\infty$-category theory the best kind of uniqueness we get is that the space of possibilities (for homotopy limits, e.g.) is a contractible $\infty$-groupoid.

Comment: I do understand that this is *not really* a problem for category theorists who always know and feel how to understand the definit article when speaking about *the limit* and alike. However, doesn't this *facon de parler* make category theory a kind of hermetism for outsiders? And what about automatic proof checking? Doesn't one have to formulate statements which are literally correct?

Comment: @Jochen: yes, category theorists use "the" in a slightly more sophisticated sense than is immediately apparent, and this is the sort of thing you have to pick up sooner than later to understand it. But mathematics (and other fields) is full of stuff like this. The correct way to formulate claims like "the limit of the product is the product of the limits" is that there's a natural map and that natural map is an isomorphism, which is literally true; this is also a standard category-theoretic phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps one can or should go even further advertising that the lack of literal uniqueness is **not a bug but a feature** -- not only of category theory but of all modern mathematics! This starts with the real numbers which are **a** completion of $\mathbb Q$ (either as an ordered set or as a uniform space). Eventually, the question *What is a real number* should not be solved but disappear (a variation of Wittgenstein).

Answer (score 3):

You're right that in a skeletal category, limit objects are uniquely determined, but the legs of the limiting cone are not, and you've also identified what goes wrong: the automorphisms get in the way.

A simple example which illustrates this is the following: in a skeletal category with limits, the defining diagram for the binary product $X \times X$ is to take the limit of the diagram $X \quad X$, obtaining a limit cone $X \leftarrow X \times X \rightarrow X$, but there are two equally good choices for the legs: $(\pi_1, \pi_2)$ and $(\pi_2, \pi_1)$. Really, the problem is that $X \times X$ has a non-identity automorphism: the swap.

The way to resolve this is to move from a skeletal category to a [gaunt](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category) one, which says that *every* isomorphism is the identity. A skeletal category is gaunt if and only if every automorphism is the identity.

Actually, asking for unique (co)limits is rather strong, in the following sense.

**Theorem**. In a category $\mathcal{C}$ with limits and colimits, the following are equivalent:

1. All limits are unique;
2. All colimits are unique;
3. $\mathcal{C}$ is gaunt.

**Proof**.
For (2) $\implies$ (3), suppose that all colimits are unique, and that $x \xrightarrow[f]{\sim} y$ is an isomorphism.

A colimit of the diagram $x \xrightarrow{f} y$ is $y$:

[image: identity colimit]

But another colimit of the same diagram is $x$:

[image: inverse colimit]

To see that this is a colimit, observe that any other cocone over this diagram is determined by a commutative triangle:

[image: commutative triangle]

This admits a unique factorisation through $x$:

[image: factorisation]

Hence deduce from uniqueness of colimits that $x = y$ and $f = \text{id}_x$.

For (3) $\implies$ (2), suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is gaunt.
Let $D\colon J \to \mathcal{C}$ be a diagram, and $(c, \iota), (c^\prime, \iota^\prime)$ be two colimits of $D$.
Colimits are unique up to unique isomorphism, so $c \cong c^\prime$.
Because $\mathcal{C}$ is gaunt, this isomorphism is the identity, so $c = c^\prime$.
As both $(c, \iota)$ and $(c^\prime, \iota^\prime)$ are colimits over the same diagram, they factor through each other via some isomorphism, which is necessarily the identity by gauntness, so $\iota = \iota^\prime$.

I'll leave it to you to finish the proof!